# CSS position fixed not working

Tags: css, css-position

Every time I scroll down, the navbar that I made also moves down. When I resize the window (smaller/bigger) it still moves even though I used `position:fixed`.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
nav li:nth-child(1) {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #15317E;
  font-size: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 184px;
  background-color: #15317E;
  top: 20px;
  left: 220px;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #1569C7;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <li><a href="Team.html" title="Team">The Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Info">Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="#div">Community</a></li>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed position refers to the browser window. The elements that use this position are always visible. I think the position you want is "absolute". [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecruz/ns11m7pw/8/)

```
nav li:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably some the screen size of your monitor. Maybe try something like

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    #nav {
   position:absolute;
   left:0%;
   top:10%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0;
   border: 1px yellow;
   border-bottom: none;
   width:100%;
   z-index:9943;
}
```

}

the z index might help with the overlapping issue. Then again it would be recommended if you pasted into https://jsfiddle.net/ or something so we can see what's up with your positioning problems.